# Is there a more efficient way to populate a dropdown than a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, knockout.js

I've been improving page performance, but when it comes to loading the various dropdowns I am losing too much time. is there a quicker way to populate the controls than this?

my.service.data.controls is an in-memory collection of collections of json data from an ajax call for the various controls in key/value pairs (Id, Name), Days, Years, Salutations, etc

```
$.each(my.service.data.controls.Days, function (i, p) {
     days.push(new my.models.dropdown(selectedItem)
     .Id(p.Id)
     .Name(p.Id));
});

// for creating Position Models
my.models.dropdown = function (selectedItem) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    // non-persitable properties
    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItem() === self;
    });
};
```

Comment: What is `days`, `my.….Days`, `my.….dropdown`; what are these `Id` and `Name` methods? Where exactly do you populate anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend profiling your js (if you haven't already) before you try to optimize it. The performance pain may be originating somewhere else in your code.

To get started, pop open the Chrome inspector, select the 'profiles' tab, and click start. Then load your page, click stop, and see what's up!

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I've split up the loading of my dropdowns from one large function into smaller ones, so that they're loaded as needed. So now it's death by paper-cut instead of a single stab wound. What profiling tools would you recommend?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. As it turns out, my issue was that I was pushing my item into an observable array, which in turn was firing off other listener events. The solution was to populate the entire array into a temp var, then populate the observableArray with that temp array.